# Spacing for multiple footnotes on one paragraph in r markdown

Tags: r, markdown

This is a rather simple problem that should have a simple solution, right? I have been trying to remove the space between footnote numbers and I could use some help.

Here is some sample code:

```
dat$place <- c("South Atlantic", "Gulf of Mexico", "Pacific")
Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel <- "Footnote_1"
Footnotes.list$ft_EFL <- "Footnote_2"    
Footnotes.list$ft_WFL <- "Footnote_3"

for (i in 1:length(dat$place)) {
  rmarkdown::render(Comm_Region.Rmd, 
                    output_dir = output,
                    output_file = paste0(filename,".docx"))
}
```

Here is the Comm_Region.Rmd markdown code (focusing on the code for "South Atlantic" and "Gulf of Mexico"):

```
retailers.`r if(place == "South Atlantic") {
paste0("^[",Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel,"] ^,^ ^[", Footnotes.list$ft_EFL,"]")} 
else if (place == "Gulf of Mexico") {
paste0("^[",Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel,"] ^,^ ^[", Footnotes.list$ft_WFL,"]")} 
else {
paste0("^[",Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel,"]")}`
```

This is what I'm looking for: [image: what I want]

This is what I keep getting:
[image: what I don't want]

I understand that I need to remove the spaces before and after the comma ( `^,^ ^`) to get the desired output; however, when I do that the whole code breaks and the footnotes no longer appear at the bottom of the page. I've also tried LaTex but to no avail. There must be a better way to write this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? We can't run any of your code because we don't have `place` or `Footnotes.list`. It would also be nice to mention your result format - HTML, PDF, Word, something else?

Comment: @GregorThomas I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure the additional code makes the question reproducible, Could you try it out to check or explain how it should work? Are you are running an `.Rmd` file from a separate script?

Comment: In this case, a good minimal example doesn't need any R code. If you have the text `text^[1] ^[2]` as the entire body of `Rmd` document and you compile to Word, you get the footnotes with the unwanted spaces. If you can find a syntax in text that works to eliminate the spaces, we can replicate it with R code. But I tried a couple things and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think the problem is that I need to have the "if" statement so that it outputs the appropriate footnotes for each "place". I don't really understand why it doesn't work if I remove the spaces.

Comment: Yes, I understand that in your real document you need if statements. But you don't need if statements to find out the correct syntax for two footnotes without spaces - you just need two footnotes. If we can use two hard-coded footnotes and figure out the correct syntax to generate them without spaces, then we can easily fix your code to generate that correct syntax. But it's much easier to try 10 options without `if` and `paste0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to work in LaTeX this may help using `fnpct` package.

````
---
title: "Multiple footnotes"
output: pdf_document  

header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fnpct}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{r footnotes, include=FALSE}

place <- "South Atlantic"
Footnotes.list <- list()
Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel <- "Footnote 1"
Footnotes.list$ft_EFL <- "Footnote 2"
Footnotes.list$ft_WFL <- "Footnote 3"

```



Retailers.`r if(place == "South Atlantic"){
   paste0("\\footnote{", Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel, "}\\footnote{", Footnotes.list$ft_EFL, "}")
 }else if(place == "Gulf of Mexico"){
    paste0("\\footnote{", Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel, "}\\footnote{", Footnotes.list$ft_WFL, "}")
    }else{
    paste0("\\footnote{", Footnotes.list$ft_IOModel, "}")
 }`
````

[image]